# Auto select a printer profile

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub PrintWithDefProfile()
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrinterProfile = "def"
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End Sub
```

every time i try to add this macro script to my workbook in excel it gives me a 438 error and i cant seem to fix it is there any way to fix this even ? i just want to automate a shortcut to choose from which tray paper out of my printer my docu are getting printed

Thanks in advance for the people responding !

i just tried to simplify changing printer profiles in excel instead of always changing it in printer properties

Comment: Welcome Aymane! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This post has a list of properties to set from VBA ...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup

Comment: Try: Application.ActivePrinter = "[The name of your printer] on [port]:" , look at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activeprinter

Comment: `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrinterProfile` is not valid, PageSetup does not have a PrinterProfile property.